# Get the count of the same results in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count all the results that have the same value in a mysql query but no matter what i have tried it does not give me the proper value

```
    +-----+---------------+
    | RoomType      | ID  |
    +=====+===============+
    | dining room   |  2  | 
    +-----+---------------+
    | sleeping room |  2  |
    +-----+---------------+
    | sleeping room |  2  | 
    +-----+---------------+
```

and i want to get the count of the sleeping rooms only.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT rt.RoomType, r.property_id AS ID
FROM Rooms r
INNER JOIN RoomTypes rt ON r.type = rt.id
WHERE r.property_id = '2'
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT SUM(IF(rt.RoomType = 'sleeping room', rt.RoomType, 0))
FROM Rooms r
INNER JOIN RoomTypes rt ON r.type = rt.id
WHERE r.property_id = '2'
```

but it does not give me the results i want. Any ideas?

Comment: `count()` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to sum apples and oranges

Comment: what is the result you want? Also show us sample data for both tables

Comment: to give me the sum of sleeping rooms

Comment: Dont tell me, Please show it in your question, and Include the sample data

Comment: Show us the INPUT tables as I am not sure if that table you show is input or output

Comment: the table is output with the 1st query. Please take a look at my answer and thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer and a working way like this:

```
SELECT SUM(rt.RoomType = 'sleeping room')
FROM Rooms r
INNER JOIN RoomTypes rt ON r.type = rt.id
WHERE r.property_id = '2'
```

and then it gives me the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `room_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_id` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

and some data like this:

> 1245  dining room 2
>
> 1246  bath    3
>
> 1247  dining room 2
>
> 1248  kitchen 5
>
> 104   dining room 2

This should work:

> select count(*), room_type, room_id from room_types where room_id = 2 group by room_type;

Result:

> 3 dining room 2

Hope it helps,

f.u.

Comment: but this is wrong. i only need to count the sleeping rooms